# Laravel destroy and update methods not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Trying to delete entries using the destroy method in Laravel controller.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $university = University::find($id);
    $university->delete();
    return redirect('/universities');
}
```

And this is what i'm using in the view

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['UniversityController@destroy', $university->Id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
{{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Getting no errors and browser redirects after the button is activated as instructed, but the entry still remains in the veiw list and in the DB. Using MySQL.

Posting to the DB also works fine, but having same problems with update method. No errors and get redirected as I should but no update has happened.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Country' => 'required'
    ]);

    $university = University::find($id);
    $university->Name = $request->input('Name');
    $university->Country = $request->input('Country');
    $university->save();

    return redirect('/universities');
}
```

And in view:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['UniversityController@update', $university->Id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('Name', 'Name')}}
        {{Form::text('Name', $university->Name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('Country', 'Country')}}
            {{Form::text('Country', $university->Country, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Country'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' =>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also tried running without the hidden form methods, but same result.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/universities', 'UniversityController@index');

Route::get('/universities/create', 'UniversityController@create');

Route::get('/universities/{id}/edit', 'UniversityController@edit');

Route::put('/universities/{id}', 'UniversityController@update');

Route::post('/universities/create', 'UniversityController@store');

Route::delete('/universities/{id}', 'UniversityController@destroy');
```

Comment: What version of Laravel is this?

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting form HTML? Can you paste it here?

Comment: Resulting form HTML?

Comment: Using verion 5.6.13

Comment: You've posted the Blade template code. This will generate actual HTML. Have you seen it? Can you paste it?

Comment: Added it in edit

Comment: Do you have any middleware for those routes? Is the request actually going through the `destroy` method? Is it finding the `University` model in question? Do you have any Eloquent event listeners that might be getting in the way?

Comment: @Thomas Buteler no i don't

Comment: Wild guess, but do you maybe have `SoftDeletes` on the model?

Comment: No softdelete used.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by setting public $primaryKey = 'Id'; in the model.